# Counting values obtained using the substring function in XQuery

Tags: substring, xquery

I have an XML file with the following entries:

```
<file>
 <unit id="u-1.01"/>
 <unit id="u-1.02"/>
 <unit id="u-1.03"/>
 <unit id="u-1.04"/>
 <unit id="u-1.05"/>
 <unit id="u-1.06"/>
 <unit id="u-1.07"/>
 <unit id="u-2.01"/>
 <unit id="u-2.02"/>
 <unit id="u-2.03"/>
 <unit id="u-2.04"/>
 <unit id="u-2.05"/>
 <unit id="u-2.06"/>
</file>
```

Let us assume I use the substring function to select the third character of the **id** attribute and assign it to variable *id*:

```
    for $identifiers in file/unit/@id
    let $id := substring($identifiers, 3, 1)
    return ($id)
```

Which returns the following:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

What I need is the count of each unique value: in this case, 7 for "1" and 6 for "2". How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XQuery processor does not support `group by`, fetch all unique IDs and count them on your own.

```
let $ids := file/unit/@id/substring(., 3, 1)
return
  for $uniqueID in distinct-values($ids)
  return element { "count" } {
    attribute { "id" } { $uniqueID },
      count($ids[.=$uniqueID])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use an XQuery 3.0 compatible processor (I tested using [BaseX](http://www.basex.org), use `group by` and `count()`:

```
for $identifiers in file/unit/@id
let $id := substring($identifiers, 3, 1)
group by $id
return element { "count" } {
  attribute { "id" } { $id },
  count($identifiers)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not that familiar with XQuery 3.0; I would therefore appreciate another solution.

Comment: XQuery 3.0 is XQuery with some enhancements, if your XQuery engine supports it, use it.