# XQuery - group by and count

Tags: xml, xquery

This is the structure of my XML file -

```
<A>
  <Name t="Mr.">James Bond</Name>
  <Name t="Mr.">Allen Bond</Name>
  <Name t="Mr." p="X">James Bond</Name>
  <Name t="Mr." p="X">James Bond</Name>
  <Name t="Mr.">James Bond</Name>
  <Name t="Mrs.">James Bond</Name>
  <Name t="Mrs.">James Bond</Name>
  <Name t="Mr.">James Bond</Name>
  <Name t="Mrs." p="Y">James Bond</Name>
  <Name t="Mrs." p="Y">James Bond</Name>
</A>
```

The output I am expecting is -

```
<A>
  <N>Allen Bond Mr - 1</N>
  <N>James Bond Mr - 3</N>
  <N>James Bond Mr, X - 2</N>
  <N>James Bond Mrs - 2</N>  
  <N>James Bond Mrs, Y - 2</N>
</A>
```

I am able to get the distinct names but cant add the count...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting values obtained using the substring function in XQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567209/counting-values-obtained-using-the-substring-function-in-xquery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XQuery 3.0 solution with [`group by`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by):

```
<A>{
  for $name in //Name
  let $full :=
    if(not($name/@p)) then concat($name, ' ', $name/@t)
    else concat($name, ' ', $name/@t, ', ', $name/@p)
  group by $full
  return <N>{$full, '-', count($name)}</N>
}</A>
```

XQuery 1.0 solution with [`distinct-values($arg)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-distinct-values):

```
<A>{
  let $names :=
    for $name in //Name
    return if(not($name/@p)) then concat($name, ' ', $name/@t)
    else concat($name, ' ', $name/@t, ', ', $name/@p)
  for $name in distinct-values($names)
  return <N>{$name, '-', count($names[. eq $name])}</N>
}</A>
```